# Cloudformation init - install multiple packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following parameter that asks the user what packages are to be installed:

```
  Packages:
    Description: A SPACE seperated list of packages that you want installed on this instance.
    Type: String
    Default: None
```

Then within my resource definition for EC2 instance, I have:

```
  WebServerHost:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      Comment: Install HTTP server
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              Fn::Join: [ ' ', [ !Ref Packages ] ]
```

But that doesn't work! Please can someone advise what I am doing wrong or if I am taking the wrong approach?
Thanks

Comment: "But that doesn't work!" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: cfn-signal returns a failure when trying to run the cfn-init scripts but other than that I don't see much. The logs show: 2021-11-25 13:19:47,708 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-11-25 13:19:47,709 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-packages) takes **object, not a list**. So you can't do that dynamically the way you want. You have to **explicitly specify** the correct values for `yum`, as in that case, they can't be passed to as Parameters.

The only way around that would be through [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), which you would have to develop and which would correctly setup `yum` property as object, not list.

Comment: Thanks very much - that makes sense. I will probably go down the route of just installing a pre-defined set of packages for now.